# Getting no output from command substitution?

Tags: bash, shell-script, command-substitution

I've written a few shell scripts, but have never seen this behavior and am at a loss. I've got the following simple script which runs in a bash shell:

```
LOGFILE="/var/log/constructor-events.txt"

SUBSYSTEM="$1"
DEVTYPE="$2"
DEVICE="$3"

VENDOR=$(lsusb -D "$DEVICE" | grep idVendor 2>&1)

REQUEST=$(cat <<EOF
{"data": {
    "action": "add",
    "port": {
        "type": "$SUBSYSTEM",
    },
    "drive": {
        "vendor_id": "$VENDOR",
    }
}}
EOF
)

printf "output: $VENDOR" >> $LOGFILE
printf "%s\n" "`date +%x\ %r\ %Z` $REQUEST"  >> $LOGFILE
```

This is executed from a udev rule. The positional parameters (coming from udev) have the values I expect, and I have no problem printing them to the log file. But for some reason, the `$VENDOR` variable contains no output from the `lsusb` command.

Here is the debugging I've done.

- Added stderr redirection to stdout to capture any error that may be
  occurring.
- Added the line to send the `$VENDOR` variable directly to
  the log, which is empty.
- Executed the script manually in the shell
  and printed the `$VENDOR` variable to the terminal and it's empty.
- Took the string that is contained in the `$DEVICE` variable and
  executed it directly in the shell, with this result.

  ```
  [root@host ~]# lsusb -D /dev/bus/usb/016/030 | grep idVendor
  Cannot open /dev/bus/usb/016/030
  ```

Why is the `$VENDOR` variable empty when outputting to the log file?

**EDIT:**

Here is an update after removing the redirection from the command substitution.

- Added a line to print the `$VENDOR` variable to the terminal.
- Statically assigned the value instead of using the `$DEVICE` variable.

Printing `$VENDOR` to the terminal output the error, but it still did not append to the log file! The value of `$DEVICE` IS in the log file. I believe it has something to do with the output redirection inside the command substitution.

Comment: Welcome to U&L , what is the output of `ls /dev/bus/usb/*`? [You can edit here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/412168/getting-no-output-from-command-substitution)

Comment: The error `Cannot open /dev/bus/usb/016/030` mean that `016:030` device doesn't exist.

Comment: On that bus it shows 
`/proc/bus/usb/016:
001  002  053`
But it gets that path dynamically from udev, and when i look in the log file 053 is the path it's printing so I know its getting the correct path of the device.

Comment: @GAD3R - /dev/bus/usb/016/030 was not in fact the correct path. I just used it for testing to see if I could get any output. Point being that it should have written that error to the log.

Comment: It's not the permissions because it does write to the log file. Only the output coming from `lsusb` is missing. But after thinking more about it I think that could be because `lsusb` is not running properly from the udev rule. Possibly because it is not running in the normal shell environment.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here, if `lsusb` drops an error, the error message is not redirected, only errors from `grep`. Errors from `lsusb` still go the the usual `stderr`, i.e. the terminal (or whatever `stderr` was when the script started.

```
VENDOR=$(lsusb -D "$DEVICE" | grep idVendor 2>&1)
```

E.g.

```
$ blah=$(ls -l /nonexisting | grep foo 2>&1)
ls: cannot access '/nonexisting': No such file or directory
$ echo "blah: '$blah'"
blah: ''
```

You'll need to redirect both of their outputs as a group to have the command substitution capture the error, too:

```
$ blah=$( { ls -l /nonexisting | grep foo; } 2>&1)
$ echo "blah: '$blah'"
blah: 'ls: cannot access '/nonexisting': No such file or directory'
```

Using separate redirections like `$( foo 2>&1 | grep 2>&1 )` would send the errors of the first command to the pipe, and for `grep` to filter, which in the above example would again produce an empty output.

Comment: Thanks a bunch! I was able to get stderr that way, and as I suspected there was an error. I'm seeing `lsusb: command not found`, but now I have to figure out what is causing that.