# bash get output from command

Tags: bash, macos, software-updates

I try to make a script for macOS that informs me about available software updates:

```
result=$(softwareupdate -l)
if [[ $(echo $result) = *"No new software available."* ]]; then say yes;fi
```

But the important line isn't included. Result:

```
result=$(softwareupdate -l)
softwareupdate -l
++ softwareupdate -l

No new software available.
+ result='Software Update Tool
Finding available software'

if [[ $(echo $result) = *"No new software available."* ]]; then say yes;fi
echo $result
++ echo Software Update Tool Finding available software
+ [[ Software Update Tool Finding available software = *\N\o\ \n\e\w\ \s\o\f\t\w\a\r\e\ \a\v\a\i\l\a\b\l\e\.* ]]
```

The line: "No new software available." is not included in the variable. Why?

Comment: Similar issue: [Getting no output from command substitution?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/412168)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Because the output is on `STDERR`, the *error file descriptor* output.

What I would do, to combine `STDOUT` **and** `STDERR` in `bash`:

```
if softwareupdate -l 2>&1 | grep -q "No new software available"; then
    echo "Nothing to do"
else
    echo "Update available"
fi
```

---

If you want to keep most of your code and use `[[ ]]` with string match, use:

```
result=$(softwareupdate -l 2>&1)
if [[ $result == *"No new software available"* ]]; then
    [...]
```

---

You can use `|&` instead of `2>&1 |` with bash 4.0+.  The default bash on macOS is too old to support `|&`, so you need to use `2>&1 |`, or install a newer `bash`, e.g. using Homebrew:

```
brew install bash
```

---

This code use *boolean logic*:

you can test directly the grep command or other commands, because they return 0 for true or > 0 for false.

---

`STDERR`:

> This is the secondary file descriptor to which commands print to the terminal. It's meant for messages that shouldn't be parsed by default. Redirect to stderr: `>&2`

`STDIN`:

> Standard Input is the file descriptor from which commands can read input.

`STDOUT`

> This is the primary file descriptor to which commands print to the terminal.

Comment: The result is wrong because the string "No new software available." is not included in the return of "softwareupdate -l" I don't know where this string comes from.

Comment: Can you test again ? Post edited. Please refresh.

Comment: ...softwareupdate -l |& grep -q ... returns an error and ...softwareupdate -l |>& grep -q ... returns a wrong result again.

Comment: Which error? Be precise...

Comment: A syntax error: untitled 5: line 3: syntax error near unexpected token `&'
untitled 5: line 3: `if softwareupdate -l |& grep -q "No new software available."; then'

Comment: Are you sure you run the script with bash and not zsh ?: `bash script.sh`

Comment: Maybe: `softwareupdate -l 2>&1 | grep -q "No new software available"`

Comment: softwareupdate -l 2>&1 | grep -q "No new software available" did the trick. Thank you.

Comment: Post edited accordingly

Comment: The bash version that comes standard with the Mac is a really old 3.2 release. You can install the latest release 5.2 via homebrew

Comment: Added a section with your code correction